# SQL C# Filter Similar Records

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-express

Question is related to a question I asked before, but I need a little help...

I have an interest table, which stores interests for `Seekers` and `Employers`...

Interest table is like:

```
int_id   FK_is_ID  FK_ie_ID  FK_ic_ID
-------------------------------------
1           2          null      3
2           2          null      5
3           null       1         3
4           null       3         1
5           null       2         5
6           4          null      1
6           3          1         2

FK_is_id = Seeker ID
FK_ie_id = Employer ID
FK_ic_id = Category ID
```

So when a seeker logs in, I am trying to retrieve `EMPLOYER` names who have similar interests to the logged in seeker...

I have a code which works fine, gives OUTPUT I want..

```
SqlConnection myConn2;
SqlCommand myCommand2;
SqlDataReader myReader2;
String SQL2, divjobs;

myConn2 = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ToString());
divjobs = "<ul>";
myConn2.Open();
SQL2 = "SELECT ins.int_id, ins.FK_is_ID, ine.FK_ie_ID,emp.e_name,ine.int_id FROM  Interests ins INNER JOIN Interests ine ON ins.FK_ic_ID = ine.FK_ic_ID FULL OUTER JOIN employers emp ON emp.e_id=ine.FK_ie_id WHERE  ins.FK_is_ID = @sid  AND ine.FK_ie_ID IS NOT null order by emp.e_name ASC";

myCommand2 = new SqlCommand(SQL2, myConn2);
myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", ssid);

myReader2 = myCommand2.ExecuteReader();

if (myReader2.HasRows)
{
    while (myReader2.Read())
    {
        divjobs = divjobs + "<li>" + "<a href='../employers/viewemployer.aspx?EID=" + myReader2["FK_ie_id"] + "'>" + "<div class='jtitle'>" + myReader2["e_name"] + "</div>" + "</li>";
    }
    divjobs = divjobs + "</ul>";
    joblist.InnerHtml = divjobs;
}
else
{
    joblist.InnerHtml = "<div style='font-weight:bold;padding:20px;font-size:1.2em;background-color:white;'>"+ "Looks like there is nothing to load!" + "</div>";
}

myConn2.Close();
```

The only problem is if an employer has 2 interests, the output gives same employer name twice! I want it to come only once... !

Is there anyway to do it, any help would be appreciated... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your results are at the "interest" level, but you really want it at the employer level - the following would return a distinct list of the employers with matching interests - I also threw an aggregation (count) of the matching interests for each:

```
SELECT
    ins.FK_ie_ID,
    emp.e_name,
    COUNT(ins.int_id) AS InterestCount
FROM
Interests ins 
INNER JOIN 
Interests ine 
    ON ins.FK_ic_ID = ine.FK_ic_ID 
INNER JOIN 
employers emp 
    ON emp.e_id = ine.FK_ie_id 
WHERE  
    ins.FK_is_ID = @sid  
GROUP BY 
    ins.FK_ie_ID,
    emp.e_name
order by emp.e_name ASC
```

I hope I interpreted what your wanted correctly.

Also, I found your column naming to be extremely awkward to work with.  There very well may be typos in the query because of this.  Is there a reason they are so cryptic...or, are they out of your control?

Comment: Thanks.. Thats what i was looking for... as for the column names, i  just randomly named them lol